# Scraping Website unsure of what to search for

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following website I wish to scrape recipe ingredient substitutions and amounts off. https://www.allrecipes.com/article/common-ingredient-substitutions/

I am modifying the code I generated from Bard AI and am hoping to store the data in a variable I can use in another program to generate recipes with substitutions for available ingredients. Here is the substitution scraping program I generated:

```
def scrape_ingredient_substitutions():
  """Scrape the Allrecipes website for common ingredient substitutions."""
  url = "https://www.allrecipes.com/article/common-ingredient-substitutions/"
  response = requests.get(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

  substitutions = {}
  for tr in soup.find("tr", class_=None):
    ingredient = tr.find_all("td", class_=None).text
    amount = tr.find_all("td", class_=None).text
    substitution = tr.find_all("td", class_=None).text
    substitutions[ingredient] = {"amount": amount, "substitution": substitution}

'''  Pull the information contained within <td> tags that are contained in <tr> tags.
    for td in tr.find_all("td"):
      data = td.text
      substitutions[ingredient][data] = td.text
'''
  return substitutions



subs = scrape_ingredient_substitutions()
print(subs)
```

I tried changing the find parameter to search for tr tags, but I don't know what they are called in the HTML doc or how to find them with class so I set class to None, wonder if this is the issue? I am still unsure of how to use find to search for the required information in the HTML doc. When I run my code it produces either an empty dictionary or in this case I got an indentation error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code was that you got one substation. Instead of `soup.find()`, use `soup.find_all(`) to get all the rows. Because each row is one '`<tr>`' tag, and the '`<tbody>`' is the whole table. First use `table = soup.find('tbody')`, to narrow down the search. You then get all the rows in one set by using `rows = table.find_all('tr')` Then cycle through the set and use `row.get_text()`. Use `row.strip()`, to then get rid of extra spaces. You then `row.split('\n')` to make it into one list per row. Make a dictionary and then the cycle repeats.

```
def scrape_ingredient_substitutions():
  #URK
  url = "https://www.allrecipes.com/article/common-ingredient-substitutions/"
  
  response = requests.get(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
  #Get the Table
  Table = soup.find("tbody")
  #find all the rows
  Rows = soup.find_all("tr")[1:]
  substitutions = {}
  Progress = 0
  String = ''
  for row in Rows:
    #making it readable
    SubRow = row.get_text().strip().replace('\xa0OR\xa01','').replace('\xa0OR\xa02', '').split('\n')
    #making a 2D Dictionary
    substitutions[SubRow[0]] = {'amount': SubRow[1], 'substitution': SubRow[2]}
#returning the dictionary
  return substitutions  
    
    
  



subs = scrape_ingredient_substitutions()
print(subs)
```

Answer (score -1):

I have analyzed the code you shared and identified an issue in the `soup.find("tr")` section. I suggest considering using `find_all` instead of find. Additionally, you could employ selectors, which can be more intuitive in some cases. For example, with `soup.select('tbody tr')`, you can obtain all rows (tr) of your table, which will make it easier to extract data such as ingredients, quantity, and substitutes.

It is worth mentioning that, while reviewing the page's code, I noticed the presence of the \xa0 symbol, which represents a non-breaking space, commonly associated with the bolding of the term "OR". Although this information may seem minor in this context, it is essential to keep it in mind for more complex future projects.

Below, I provide you with the corrected code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def scrape_ingredient_substitutions():
    """Scrape the Allrecipes website for common ingredient substitutions."""
    url = "https://www.allrecipes.com/article/common-ingredient-substitutions/"
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
    substitutions = {}
    rows = soup.select('tbody tr')

    for i in range(1, len(rows)):
        cols = [td.get_text() for td in rows[i].select('td')]
        # substitutions[ingredient] = {"amount": amount, "substitution": substitution}
        substitutions[cols[0]] = {"amount": cols[1], "substitution": cols[2].replace('\xa0', ' ')}

    '''  Pull the information contained within <td> tags that are contained in <tr> tags.
        for td in tr.find_all("td"):
        data = td.text
        substitutions[ingredient][data] = td.text
    '''
    return substitutions


subs = scrape_ingredient_substitutions()
for ingr in subs:
    print("%s: %s" %(ingr, subs[ingr]))
```

Output:

```
Allspice: {'amount': '1 teaspoon', 'substitution': '1/2 teaspoon cinnamon, 1/4 teaspoon ginger, and 1/4 teaspoon cloves'}
Arrowroot starch: {'amount': '1 teaspoon', 'substitution': '1 tablespoon flour OR 1 teaspoon cornstarch'}
Baking mix: {'amount': '1 cup', 'substitution': '1 cup pancake mix'}
Baking powder: {'amount': '1 teaspoon', 'substitution': '1/4 teaspoon baking soda plus 1/2 teaspoon cream of tartar OR 1/4 teaspoon baking soda plus 1/2 cup buttermilk (decrease liquid in recipe by 1/2 cup)'}
Baking soda: {'amount': '1 teaspoon', 'substitution': '4 teaspoons baking powder OR 1 teaspoon potassium bicarbonate and 1/3 teaspoon salt. NOTE: If the recipe calls for an acidic liquid such as sour cream, yogurt, buttermilk, vinegar, molasses, or citrus juice, you should replace it with the same amount of whole milk'}
Beer: {'amount': '1 cup', 'substitution': '1 cup nonalcoholic beer OR 1 cup chicken broth'}
Brandy: {'amount': '1/4 cup', 'substitution': '1 teaspoon imitation brandy extract plus enough water to make 1/4 cup'}
Bread crumbs: {'amount': '1 cup', 'substitution': '1 cup cracker crumbs OR 1 cup matzo meal OR 1 cup ground oats'}
Broth: beef or chicken: {'amount': '1 cup', 'substitution': '1 bouillon cube plus 1 cup boiling water OR 1 tablespoon soy sauce plus enough water to make 1 cup OR 1 cup vegetable broth'}
Brown sugar: {'amount': '1 cup, packed', 'substitution': "1 cup white sugar plus 1/4 cup molasses and decrease the liquid in recipe by 1/4 cup OR 1 cup white sugar OR 1 1/4 cups confectioners' sugar"}
Butter (salted): {'amount': '1 cup', 'substitution': '1 cup margarine OR 1 cup shortening plus 1/2 teaspoon salt OR 7/8 cup vegetable oil plus 1/2 teaspoon salt OR 7/8 cup lard plus 1/2 teaspoon salt'}
Butter (unsalted): {'amount': '1 cup', 'substitution': '1 cup shortening OR 7/8 cup vegetable oil OR 7/8 cup lard'}
Buttermilk: {'amount': '1 cup', 'substitution': '1 cup yogurt OR 1 tablespoon lemon juice or vinegar plus enough milk to make 1 cup'}
Cheddar cheese: {'amount': '1 cup shredded', 'substitution': '1 cup shredded Colby cheddar OR 1 cup shredded Monterey Jack cheese'}
Chervil: {'amount': '1 tablespoon chopped fresh', 'substitution': '1 tablespoon chopped fresh parsley'}
Chicken base: {'amount': '1 tablespoon', 'substitution': '1 cup canned or homemade chicken broth or stock. Reduce liquid in recipe by 1 cup'}
Chocolate (semisweet): {'amount': '1 ounce', 'substitution': '1 (1-ounce) square of unsweetened chocolate plus 4 teaspoons sugar OR 1 ounce semisweet chocolate chips plus 1 teaspoon shortening'}
Chocolate (unsweetened): {'amount': '1 ounce', 'substitution': '3 tablespoons unsweetened cocoa plus 1 tablespoon shortening or vegetable oil'}
Cocoa: {'amount': '1/4 cup', 'substitution': '1 (1-ounce) square unsweetened chocolate'}
Condensed cream of mushroom soup: {'amount': '1 (10.75-ounce) can', 'substitution': '1 (10.75-ounce) can condensed cream of celery, cream of chicken, or golden mushroom soup'}
Corn syrup: {'amount': '1 cup', 'substitution': '1 1/4 cup white sugar plus 1/3 cup water OR 1 cup honey OR 1 cup light treacle syrup'}
Cottage cheese: {'amount': '1 cup', 'substitution': "1 cup farmer's cheese OR 1 cup ricotta cheese"}
Cracker crumbs: {'amount': '1 cup', 'substitution': '1 cup bread crumbs OR 1 cup matzo meal OR 1 cup ground oats'}
Cream (half and half): {'amount': '1 cup', 'substitution': '7/8 cup milk plus 1 tablespoon butter'}
Cream (heavy): {'amount': '1 cup', 'substitution': '1 cup evaporated milk OR 3/4 cup milk plus 1/3 cup butter'}
Cream (light): {'amount': '1 cup', 'substitution': '1 cup evaporated milk OR 3/4 cup milk plus 3 tablespoons butter'}
Cream (whipped): {'amount': '1 cup', 'substitution': '1 cup frozen whipped topping, thawed'}
Cream of tartar: {'amount': '1 teaspoon', 'substitution': '2 teaspoons lemon juice or vinegar'}
Crème fraiche: {'amount': '1 cup', 'substitution': 'Combine 1 cup of heavy cream and 1 tablespoon of plain yogurt. Let stand for 6 hours at room temperature'}
Egg: {'amount': '1 whole (3 tablespoons or 1.7 oz)', 'substitution': '2 1/2 tablespoons of powdered egg substitute plus 2 1/2 tablespoons water OR 1/4 cup liquid egg substitute OR 1/4 cup silken tofu pureed OR 3 tablespoons mayonnaise OR half a banana mashed with 1/2 teaspoon baking powder OR 1 tablespoon powdered flax seed soaked in 3 tablespoons water'}
Evaporated milk: {'amount': '1 cup', 'substitution': '1 cup light cream'}
...
```